# Alpine netboot APKs at boot time

Tags: alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper, ipxe

I new to alpine linux, so I didn't really grasped the concept of it yet.

**What I want to accomplish is a netboot alpine with apks that aren't included in the alpine-base pkg. For example `sudo` `python3`**

I managed to boot alpine with dnsmasq's tftp server and lighttpd.

As far I understand I can provide an `overlay.tar.gz` in `cmdline.txt`. If i add the alpine repo to `/etc/apk/repositories` and then `apk add` the pkgs then save the overlay and boot with it, it will have the pkgs I need.

But then it will load them from the external alpine repos.

What I want is to have them served with my http server.

**What is the best way to do this?**

I figured I could maybe add the pkgs in the `APKINDEX.tar.gz` and the corresponding .apk-s to the http server.

But this doesn't really seem to be a good solution in my opinion.

Or is it?

Or maybe I should make a custom alpine image and then boot that?

Any help would be much appreciated, because I don't think I even managed to formulate the problem, since I didn't really found anything on the internet yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the easyest solution:

Serving an extra repository with the http server with the needed packages, adding the repository to `/etc/apk/repositories`, and including the packages in `/etc/apk/world`.

This way when it boots it will install the additional packages from the extra repository.